# Magento is not loading css on the first load

Tags: css, magento, load

I am working on the Magento website. http://www.idealtilenyc.com/

CSS on Home page is not loaded, but only on the first load. If you click any link(Products, Gallery,...), CSS is loaded and works fine. What might be the reason that it does not appear on a first load?

Thank You!

Comment: Did you change any code or settings in admin panel? if so, post those changes here.

Comment: actually, I did a lot of changes. And I know, that probably it's my fault :) But I don't know how to debug this problem. Which part of the code would be useful, what might have affected this?

Answer (score 1):

If you review GET requests that your homepage makes it reveals that this style sheet is not found:

http://www.idealtilenyc.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css

Other pages uses different location:

http://www.idealtilenyc.com/skin/frontend/default/default/my_igallery/css/styles.css

Is it possible that there could be some problems in "Package" settings in your admin section (System > Configuration > Design > Package).

Try review this setting in different scopes (the selectbox on the left side of the admin page labeled "Current Configuration Scope:")

Comment: HI! thanks! It might be the reason. I am using "blank" theme in magento, but when i tried to change "package"->blank (now it says "default") there appeared a message. "An error occurred while saving this configuration: package with this name does not exist and cannot be set."

Comment: I've checked /base/default/css folder, and styles.css actually was missing, I copied styles.css from my /default/blank/css folder. Now some of the styling is missing on the first load on Home page (like Logo, recomended products, and so on... ) I am wondering what is the correct way of fixing this problem, because mine obviously isn't the best one :)

Comment: Copying styles isn't solution just workaround :) Unfortunately I've never set up design packages on my own.
Try to figure it out from documentation here:
[Theme hierarchy](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)
[Working with themes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes)